# Go back to same JSP that sent request with RequestDispatcher in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, forward, requestdispatcher

I have a servlet which can get requests by multiple JSP's.

But when I use the RequestDispatcher in the servlet, I don't know how to forward to the JSP that sent the request.

```
req.getRequestDispatcher("page.jsp").forward(req, resp);
```

I know there is something like this in html: javascript:javascript:history.go(-1)

I just need something like this:

```
req.setAttribute("originalRequest", req.getRequestPage());
req.getRequestDispatcher(originalRequest).forward(req, resp);
```

That piece of code is probably very noob but it gives you the idea of what I need.

So: I need to forward to the page that sent the original request (basically reload the page), but because multiple jsp's use the servlet, I cannot simply forward to "page.jsp"

Comment: So you want to forward the request from `JSP A` to `JSP B`, and once in `JSP B` back to `JSP A`?

Comment: Also, it seems like you are mixing forwarding and redirection. Do you know what the difference is? `history.go(...)` shows redirection, but your write you want to use forwarding in your JSP. What do you need, really? It seems like the problem is more a design than a code problem.

Comment: I have JSP A, JSP B, ServletC.
When JSP A sends a request to ServletC, the requestdispatcher should "forward/redirect" to JSP A.
When JSP B sends a request to ServletC, the requestdispatcher should "forward/redirect" to JSP B.

I'm not sure what the difference between forward and redirect is but it should just go to that same page the request came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do following

- Create a hidden parameter for every jsp named `jspName` and give value for respective JSPs. e.g. for JSP A, parameter name is `jspName` and value is `a`, for JSP B, parameter name is `jspName` and value is `b`
- Read this hidden parameter in the servlet using following code.

  ```
  String jspName = request.getParameter("jspName");
  RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(jspName);

  rd.forward(request, response);
  ```

When you are calling the servlet from JSP A, then it will have paramter `japName=a`, when servlet code is running, it will retrieve the value `a` from `request.getParamter("jspName")` and a `getRequestDispatcher(jspName)` will create the dispatcher for the same and `rd.forward(request, response)` will forward to the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried the following, but I hope this may help you to solve your problem.

```
req.setAttribute("originalRequest", req.getRequestPage());
req.getRequestDispatcher(req.getAttribute(originalRequest).toString()).forward(req, resp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried in this way, It's working for me...

**In JSP**

You need to set this in every JSP. For ex: index.jsp is my jsp name.

```
<% session.setAttribute("jspName","index.jsp"); %>
```

**In Servlet**

```
request.getRequestDispatcher(session.getAttribute("jspName").toString()).forward(req, res);
```